# SimpleFormatData retornando null HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, datetime, formatação

Preciso pegar apenas o horário informado pelo usuário, mas o método que fiz retorna `null` quando tento mudar o formato para `HH:mm:ss`

```
public static Date formataData(String data) throws Exception {
    if (data == null || data.equals(""))
        return null;
    Date date = null;
    try {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(data);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return date;
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText peso = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pesotxt);
    final EditText iniciosono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iniciohorario);
    final EditText fimsono = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fimhorario);


                    Date hInicioSono = null;
                    Date hFimSono = null;
                    try {
                        hInicioSono = formataData(iniciosono.getText().toString());
                        hFimSono = formataData(fimsono.getText().toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Quando chamo o método:

```
    hInicioSono = formataData(iniciosono.getText().toString());
```

O que acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que o date saísse `23:00`, mas sai `"Thu Jan 01 23:00:00 BRT 1970`".
Preciso verificar se o horário atual está entre `inicioSono` e `FimSono` mas nunca vai estar pois a data vem sempre 1970.

Comment: O que está sendo passado para esse método? Se está retornando null é porque ou está sendo passada uma string vazia ou nula. Veja aqui não deu problema: https://ideone.com/LJyVCv

Comment: @Florida não necessariamente, veja o link que postei, não alterei nada do código dela e funcionou normalmente. O problema ai é a entrada, o método em si não tem problema aparente.

Comment: Já vi, por isso apaguei. =/ Seria bom ele colocar a linha usada para chamar essa função.

Comment: Já depurei e a string n é nula, quando chega na linha "date = (java.util.Date)formatter.parse(data);" passa direto

Comment: O que é `iniciosono`? Adicione um [mcve] fica dificil analisar pedaços avulsos de código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma das formas é retornar uma `String` mesmo, uma vez que o parse não problema:

```
public static String formataData(String data) throws Exception {
    if (data == null || data.equals(""))
        return null;
    Date date = null;
    DateFormat formatter;
    try {
        formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        date = (java.util.Date) formatter.parse(data);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return formatter.format(date);
}
```

Funcionando no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/LJyVCv)

Ou já que você só precisa comparar horário, sem levar em conta a data, pode usar a classe [**LocalTime**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) do pacote `java.time` de java 8:

```
public static LocalTime formataData(String data) throws Exception {
    if (data == null || data.equals(""))
        return null;
    LocalTime lt = LocalTime.parse(data);
    return lt;
}
```

Veja também em funcionamento no [**IDEONE**](https://ideone.com/vYmZ7Q).

Para usar este último método, seria necessário também alterar o tipo das suas variáveis `hInicioSono` e `hFimSono`:

```
LocalTime hInicioSono;
LocalTime hFimSono;
```

Comment: Deu certo! Usei o método de retornar String